# USB storage devices only work in one port

Tags: windows-10, usb-storage

On a newly-built Win10 x64 Pro machine, only one of the front-panel USB ports works with storage media -- any type, I've tried known-good thumb drives, SD card readers, a DVD burner, and external HDDs, all of which have also been used on many other PCs and laptops without issues. The other 8 USB ports recognize other devices like a mouse or keyboard but do not work with storage devices. I flashed BIOS using a thumb drive in non-working port, so this seems to be a Windows issue, not a hardware problem.

All 8 non-working ports behave the same way: Windows *recognizes* the device, but it indicates the file system is corrupt. As soon as you connect a writable device, Windows prompts to format it, and Disk Manager shows the filesystem as raw. Formatting fails immediately, and even DISKPART can't read/write the devices. When the DVD burner is attached, Windows appears to behave as if a blank, writable disk is installed. I attached multiple devices, no change in behavior, they get a drive letter but can't be read or written.

I built the machine yesterday, everything is brand new, and this happened immediately after setup and driver installation, no other software of any kind installed. The motherboard is an MSI X570 Meg Ace. I started with the drivers from the included disc, I let Windows do the update thing, I downloaded all the latest drivers from MSI, I flashed the latest BIOS from AMD, and finally I forced an update to Windows version 20H2. No change in behavior. I doubt it matters, but my install media was a USB drive in the same working port (didn't try other ports).

There is nothing in Event Viewer (which makes sense, given Windows recognizes a storage device is attached and can see the device name etc, Windows doesn't report any errors). I downloaded [usbdeview](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) and compared the detailed device configuration for the same thumb drive in the working and a few non-working ports, and there were no differences.

Not sure what else to try. Everything else on the machine is working normally.

Comment: Did you try to use external drives with a dedicated power supply (e.g. a docking station), or otherwise a little USB stick? E.g. 2.5" cases usually need to be powered by USB only, but not all USB ports serve enough power to do so, especially the ones on the front-panel which are attached via longer cables to the motherboard where some voltage drop is the result. I wouldn't expect such issues on newer boards + USB 3 anymore, but on older ones it was common and the reason why the 2.5" cases often had a Y-cable with two USB A plugs.

Comment: I'm aware of possible power issues for traditional drives, but thumb drives and SD card readers don't have that issue and those also do not work.